# Mac: how to set the process priority

Tags: macos, process

I am writing a music player and it make sense to have the process which plays the music running with a higher priority to avoid underuns.

Simply using `nice(-5)` didn't worked - I get the error `[Errno 1] Operation not permitted` which looks like I need superuser rights.

But do I really need them?

How are iTunes or other players doing it? They don't ask me for my admin password, so they don't use superuser rights.

---

**Edit:** I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/scheduler/scheduler.html) which describes how it works for OSX for threads. This mostly answers my question - but not fully though because I think I need it for the whole process in my case.